# Jquery - Dynamically populate select options from img alt tags on page

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

So I have a web page with a list of images populated from a CMS. Each image has an Alt tag which I would like to extract the content from and populate a select box further down the page with.

Using jquery how would I find all images on the page with a set class, then extrapolate the ALT value from each image that matches, and then dynamically create the option values/string of a select box with the image ALT text?

Any help would be most appreciated.

EDIT: Question 2
@gavgrif Thank you for help, one final question if I may, So I have managed to get my select box (#imageSelection) options populated by jquery as per your answer, however, when I post the form via AJX I'm getting the following 
value **object htmlselectelement** rather than the value that the options have been populated with.

In my AJAX > Form Script I'm defining the following ...

```
var image = $("#imageSelection").val();
```

for my other form inputs .val() is working fine.

If you can point me in the right direction (AGAIN) that would be most appreciated.

Regards
Geoff

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying @TheYaXxE s answer - You don't need to iterate over the images to get the class - just make sure that it is a unique class for the images and then use the class as a direct selector.

```js
$('.take-this').each(function() {
 var altValue = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('<option value='+altValue+'>'+altValue+'</option>').appendTo($('select'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="take-this" alt="One"/>
<img class="take-this" alt="Two"/>
<img class="not-this" alt="Three"/>
<img class="not-this" alt="Four"/>
<img class="take-this" alt="five"/>
<br/>
<select name="select">
</select>
```

Comment: WOW thank you guys! I have been pondering this issue for 4+ hours, trying to figure it out. Thank you both for your help, @gavgrif your solution is perfect for my needs thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help - one more thing - don't forget that you should have size attributes in the image declarations as well - and also that the ALT  text is meant to be used if the image for whatever reason is not loaded or is blocked  - therefore the text should really be a representation of the content or message that the image was meant to provide. If you want to use a less descriptive text - then you could add a data-attribute and use that instead of the alt text

Comment: Heey. You stole my answer! :O :)

Comment: Thank you guys and great point about the data-attr, I'm working with what the CMS outputs at the moment, so will looks to edit the solution when I can get the proof of concept working.

How do I add a 2nd question to this thread? I'm having issues with the posted value of the Select  i.e [object HTMLSelectElement]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
$('img.take-this').each(function() {
    var altValue = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('<option value='+altValue+'>'+altValue+'</option>').appendTo($('select'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="take-this" alt="One"/>
<img class="take-this" alt="Two"/>
<img class="not-this" alt="Three"/>
<img class="not-this" alt="Four"/>
<img class="take-this" alt="five"/>
<br/>
<select name="select">
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry - I didn't steal it - you had a solution that I modified and then credited you with in my answer. The main difference was that you were checking to see if the element had the specified class and then if so - did the function - my point was that you didn't need to do the check and that you could just iterate over the elements with the specified class - an approach that I saw you edited your answer to after I posted mine. So I did not steal the answer - I improved upon it and inspired the edit to yours. but i did use your code as a start- which is why I credited you with it in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $selector = $('.imgSelector');
  var options = '';

  $('body img').each(function(indx, val){
    options += '<option>' + $(val).attr('alt') + '</option>' 
  });
  console.log(options);
  $selector.html(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <img alt="alt 1" />
  <img alt="alt 2" />
  <img alt="alt 3" />
  <img alt="alt 4" />
  <img alt="alt 5" />
  <select class="imgSelector"></select>
</body>
```

It's depend of your needs and more explanation of your goal can make changes in code.